# Angular 2 Observable to Observable []

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Not sure if the title is accurate as not sure of the exact terminology.

Suppose I have some code like the the below.

When I load an individual resource using the first method I can create an instance of a rich model class which wraps/decorates the plain JS object in the function passed to map(...).

How can I achieve same in the second method where the response is an array of Course objects?

```
@Injectable()
export class CourseService {

  constructor(private restangular: Restangular) {

  }

  public getCourse(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.restangular.one("courses", id).get().map(response =>
      new Course(response)
    );
  }

  public getAllCourses(): Observable<any> {
    return this.restangular.all("courses").getList().map(response => {
      //an array of courses
      console.log(response);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the second method receives an array, you can use `Array.map()` to iterate on the values of the array and convert each value into a `Course` instance:

```ts
public getAllCourses(): Observable<any> {
  return this.restangular.all("courses").getList().map(response => {
    return response.map(courseData => new Course(courseData));
  });
}
```

This code can be confusing because:

- The 1st `.map()` is [Observable.map()](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-map) (from RxJS library).
- The 2nd `.map()` is [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (plain JavaScript).

For brevity, you could write the method body on a single line (thus avoiding the inner `return`):

```ts
public getAllCourses(): Observable<any> {
  return this.restangular.all("courses").getList().map(response => response.map(courseData => new Course(courseData)));
}
```

But it's slightly harder to read. :)

Answer (score 0):

What are you thinking about this approach?

```
@Injectable()
export class CourseService {

  constructor(private restangular: Restangular) {

  }

  public getCourse(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.restangular.one("courses", id).get().map(response =>
      new Course(response)
    );
  }

  public getAllCourses(): Observable<any> {
    return this.restangular.all("courses").getList().map(response => {
      //an array of courses
      let courses = [];
      for (let courseData of response) {
        courses.push(new Course(courseData);
      }
      return courses;
    });
  }
}
```

Does this fit to your problem?

Answer (score -1):

You can simply doing it with

```
public getAllCourses(): Observable<Course[]> {
    return this.restangular.all("courses").getList().map((resp: Response) => resp.json());
}
```