# How the observable will return multiple values over time

Tags: javascript, angular

```
class Users {
    constructor(private http: HTTPClient) {
    }
    const getUsers = this.http.get('url').map(res => res);
    getUsers.subscribe( res => console.log('Response : ' +res) );
}
```

Here how getUsers observable will return multiple values over time.

Can someone please help me to understand on this. Thanks

Comment: What are you asking here? That code will do a single Http request, and in the subscribe you will receive the response of the request. Do you want to know how you could regularly do the request?

Comment: check this out 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41911568/angular-2-observable-to-observable

Comment: I have seen from the documentation saying that observable will return multiple values over time whereas promise will not.
Here how it will happen. I was just making an async request it will process it and returns the reponse one time.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing an HTTP request there and since you are subscribed to `getUsers`, you will receive the response once it has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It won't fire multiple times in your example.
But the power of being and `Observable` instead of a mere `Promise` here, is that you can you have the power of RxJS at your fingertips to do advanced data manipulations.

As an (maybe silly) example:

```
class Users {
   constructor(private http: HTTPClient) {
    }
    const getUsers = this.http.get('url');
    const users = getUsers.map(res => res.value.users);
    users.map(users => users.map(user => user.name)).subscribe(userNames => { ... });
    getUsers.subscribe( res => console.log('Response : ' +res) );
```

}